# Why wasn't Loki injured in the opening scene of Infinity War?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, loki

During the opening scene of *Avengers: Infinity War* we see Loki completely uninjured as if he wasn't present on the ship of which we know that he was. Why wasn't he injured like Heimdall, Thor, and the rest?

Comment: “as if he wasn't present on the ship” — or as if he didn't fight, instead biding his time until he could use the trickery he's famous for.

Comment: Maybe Thanos' thugs were busy beating up Loki's illusions while the real Loki was sipping Asgardian beer.

Answer (score 6):

Loki was a prisoner of the Black Order at the start of *Avengers: Infinity War*, likely by choice. Loki is not a fighter and so it doesn't make sense for him to get into a big battle with people who *are* fighters. Instead his talent lies in being a trickster and being sneaky.

> Ebony Maw joined the Black Guard as they surrounded their prisoner—Loki, the God of Mischief himself.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War* - Novelisation</sub>

[image: Loki with the Black Order]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

We see this later on after he has given up the Tesseract to Thanos, he starts trying to play the double agent again. He tries to make it seem as if he is Thanos' ally and then strike at the last second to take him down. And it almost worked if Thanos hadn't already had the Space Stone.

> **Loki:** I consider experience, experience. Almighty Thanos, I... Loki... Prince of Asgard... [looks significantly at Thor] Odinson... the rightful King of Jotunheim... God of Mischief... do hereby pledge to you, my undying fidelity.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

So, he wasn't injured because he probably didn't join in on the fight, had he joined in, he would have been injured similar to Thor and Heimdall.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Both novelisation and film make it pretty clear that he is a prisoner. Note that in the image included, weapons are being pointed at Loki, and the scene in question involves Thanos literally torturing his brother to make him give up the Tesseract, which he initially refuses to give up.

It's only later when he offers to be a guide, after the Hulk fight, that he's pretending to try and get back into Thanos' good graces. What he does before he is captured (the question being asked here) is not being answered in this answer.

Comment: @DariM I've reworded the answer. I was watching it back on my phone last night with poor quality so missed a few details. The only thing I would say though is I wouldn't read too much into refusing to give up the Tesseract that's just Loki being Loki. Even if he was on Thanos' side then he'd probably still pretend he didn't have it.